# How can I access View Blocks from a Helper in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I'd like to access a View Block that I setup in my View from within a Helper function.  I can't seem to figure it out, though.

Here's what I'd like to be able to do:

*View File:*

```
<? $this->start('someblock'); ?>
  Some content goes here.
<? $this->end(); ?>
```

*Helper:*

```
function do_something() {
  debug($this->fetch('someblock');
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to access the content of the View Blocks from the Helper.  I would rather not pass the data over in a variable -- I already know how to do that.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All helpers extend `helper.php` which sets a `_View` property for the current view.

So you'd use:

```
$this->_View->start('someblock');
```

Comment: That sounds like a great way to start a block from within a helper, but what if I started the block in the View, and I want to access it from the helper?

Example: I use $this->start('someblock') in my View, and then I call $this->SomeHelper->somefunc().  Can I access 'someblock' from within 'SomeHelper'?

Comment: Yes, `$this->_View` points to the same View object.  Most of the time there is only one View object during the Cake request life cycle. (a notable exception could be sending an email -- it uses it's own View object)